# Unable to send Stream but able to send string to Restful service from Windows Phone 7?

Tags: sql-server, wcf, windows-phone-7, restful-url

I have been trying to send a image to restful service and some data with it. But i can send data (Name and Description of image) and also i created sql database to store data and data is added on it but i can't send image to the server.

the code for service:

```
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadPhoto/{fileName}/{description}", Method = "POST")]
    public void UploadPhoto(string fileName, string description, Stream fileContents)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
        do
        {
            bytesRead = fileContents.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

            ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        } while (bytesRead > 0);

        // Save the photo on database.
        using (DataAcess data = new DataAcess())
        {
            var photo = new Photo() { Name = fileName, Description = description, Data = ms.ToArray(), DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow,  };
            data.InsertPhoto(photo);
        }

        ms.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Uploaded file {0} with {1} bytes", fileName, totalBytesRead);
    }
```

And this is my code on client side. I am doing it on windows phone 7.

```
 void btnNewPhoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:2557/photos");
        string requestUrl = string.Format("{0}/UploadPhoto/{1}/{2}", uri, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(txtFileName.Text), txtDescription.Text);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.BeginGetRequestStream
            (result =>
            {
                // Sending the request.
                using (var requestStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
                    {
                        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(requestStream);
                        string s = imgPhoto.ToString();
                        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s.ToString());
                        requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

                        requestStream.Close();
                        requestStream.Dispose();
                        //writer.Write(requestUrl);
                        //writer.Flush();

                    }
                }



                // Getting the response.
                request.BeginGetResponse(responseResult =>
                {
                    var webResponse = request.EndGetResponse(responseResult);
                    using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {

                            string srresult = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }, null);
            }, null);
    }
```

Comment: You'll want to change your Uri. You cannot use "localhost". Set it to the computer name or website

Comment: Thanks for reply Shawn but I am hosting it locally.

Comment: IF you are using the emulator and IF you are only targeting phone 7, make sure to follow this post http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Is it for soap? I want to call it from restful service..